# Why can I access to static private property of a class with bracket notation but not with dot notation?

Tags: typescript

This small example is illustrated my question:

```
class Foo{
    private static g = 'hello'    
}

console.log(Foo['g'])//hello
console.log(Foo.g)//Property 'g' is private and only accessible within class 'Foo'.
```

Why at all available access to private property `Foo['g'] == hello` ?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28DeAoa7oAcBOBLAbmAC4Cm0ERxuw0A5tALzQDkAFiSCPMxtCgL4oUweADsI8ECQB0XWgAoE8ANrNazALoBKYWIlTZ8BUum0tAenMAFbPEwlsRAJ4t10XDBwFiZMKIAm0GIgLmDAwCRQuABGUtAA7rhErLii0KCQMMxKzNJAA)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335 is the authoritative answer to this. See other q/a for details.